# How do I solve SIGSEGV ERROR in this question?

Tags: segmentation-fault

Addition

Recently, Chef studied the binary numeral system and noticed that it is extremely simple to perform bitwise operations like AND, XOR or bit shift on non-negative integers, while it is much more complicated to perform arithmetic operations (e.g. addition, multiplication or division).

After playing with binary operations for a while, Chef invented an interesting algorithm for addition of two non-negative integers A and B:

function add(A, B):     while B is greater than 0:         U = A XOR B         V = A AND B         A = U         B = V * 2     return A Now Chef is wondering how fast this algorithm is. Given the initial values of A and B (in binary representation), he needs you to help him compute the number of times the while-loop of the algorithm is repeated.

Input The first line of the input contains a single integer T denoting the number of test cases. The description of T test cases follows. The first line of each test case contains a single string A. The second line contains a single string B. Output For each test case, print a single line containing one integer ― the number of iterations the algorithm will perform during addition of the given numbers A and B.

Constraints 1≤T≤105 1≤|A|,|B|≤105 A and B contain only characters '0' and '1' the sum of |A|+|B| over all test cases does not exceed 106 Subtasks Subtask #1 (20 points): |A|,|B|≤30 Subtask #2 (30 points):

|A|,|B|≤500 the sum of |A|+|B| over all test cases does not exceed 105 Subtask #3 (50 points): original constraints

Example Input 3 100010 
0 0 100010 11100 1010 Example Output 0 1 3 Explanation Example case 1: The initial value of B is 0, so while-loop is not performed at all.

Example case 2: The initial values of A and B are 02=0 and 1000102=34 respectively. When the while-loop is performed for the first time, we have:

U=34 V=0 A changes to 34 B changes to 2⋅0=0 The while-loop terminates immediately afterwards, so it is executed only once.

Example case 3: The initial values of A and B are 111002=28 and 10102=10 respectively. After the first iteration, their values change to 22 and 16 respectively. After the second iteration, they change to 6 and 32, and finally, after the third iteration, to 38 and 0.

My solution:-

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int i,k,count,t;
char A[20],B[20];
int a,b,u,v;
scanf("%d",&t);
while(t--)
{
    int sum;
    a=0; b=0;
    fflush(stdin);
    cin>>A;
    fflush(stdin);
    cin>>B;
    for(i=0;i<strlen(A);i++)
    {
        a=a*2+A[i]-48;
    }
    //cout<<"a="<<a<<endl;
    for(i=0;i<strlen(B);i++)
    {
        b=b*2+B[i]-48;
    }
    sum=a+b;
    //cout<<"b="<<b<<endl;
    for(k=0;b>0;k++)
    {
        u=a^b;
        a=u;
        b=sum-a;
        //cout<<a<<b<<endl;
    }   
    cout<<k<<endl;    
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you actually have a question? You forgot to ask it.

Comment: This is a currently-active competition question on CodeChef: https://www.codechef.com/DEC19B/problems/BINADD

Comment: sum-a ??
How will this give you the no. of  iterations
You are trying brute right ?

Answer (score 0):

Just increase the size of character array and it will work just change it to 200001

Answer (score 0):

```
t=int(input())
while(t!=0):
    A=int(input(),2)
    B=int(input(),2)
    c=0
    while(B>0):
        U = A^B
        V = A&B
        A = U
        B = V*2
        c=c+1
    print(c)
    t-=1
```

Comment: Please add some text to describe why this might be an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I tried brute force but it is not working, here is my code

```
int main() {
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        string stra,strb;
        long int a=0,b=0;
        fflush(stdin);
        cin>>stra;
        fflush(stdin);
        cin>>strb;

        for(std::string::size_type i=0;i<stra.size();i++)
        {
            int ax=stra[i];
            ax-=48;
            a+=ax*pow(10,stra.size()-i-1);
        }
        for(std::string::size_type i=0;i<strb.size();i++)
        {
            int bx=strb[i];
            bx-=48;
            b+=bx*pow(10,strb.size()-i-1);
        }


        long int runtime=0;
        while(b>0)
        {
            long int V,U;
            U = a ^ b;
            V = a & b;
            a = U;
            b = V * 2;
            runtime++;
        }
        cout<<runtime<<endl;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Answers should contain code that do work, or at least provide a partial solution. What's the point in providing not working code? :)